# add dynamically items to a menu and make them appear at next restart

Tags: java, android, menu, menuitem

I have been developing an app in Android. I have created a menu with some static elements:

```
<menu
    android:id="@+id/submenu">
    <item android:id="@+id/create_new"
        android:title="eganaude" />
    <item android:id="@+id/open"
        android:title="skema" />
</menu>
```

and I have a rule to add other elements dynamically:

```
menu_global.add(0, new_hash_value, 0, text);
```

However, this way each time I restart the app, I should add again the elements to the menu. So I would like the new elements added dynamically to appear at each restart. Is there a way to implement this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use an internal database to keep your information, is easy to implement it, look at this link with information:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to save the new added menu items to database or shared preferences or in a file and then later read/load the items and add them to the menu

Comment: could you explain me a bit more how to do this? I understand that there should be a sort of external memory to save datas...

Comment: When ever you add a new menu item you save it somewhere, and then in the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) you just load all items and call menu.add method in a for loop or something like that